# working with result of wp_dropdown_pages()

Tags: dropdown

With `wp_dropdown_pages();` it's able to make a dropdown list with the pages of the blog.

How can I work with this function? I want to get a specific custom field of the "dropdown-selected page". Don't know the way so solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your trying to do with the custom field but you can create your own drop down select using [the `get_pages()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) which returns an array of pages similar to the `get_posts()` function.

```
$pages = get_pages();
    foreach( $pages as $page ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $page->ID, 'your_meta_key', true );
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but this just helps a little bit. In fact I need to setup a dropdown menu where a user is allowed to choose an existing page. After selecting the entered custom fields of this page will be imported to selecting page.

Comment: Please explain your question better.  So what you want want in the dropdown menu? The page?  Where does the custom field come in?  Where is the custom field supposed to appear.

Comment: The dropdown menu should list the titles of the sites (like delivered through the wp_dropdown_pages function). After choosing a side i should click on a button and the current side should import all the custom field keys and values of the chosen side into the current one. The import can be done by me easily. Just the dropdown and the function to get the page id by dropdown list is my problem

Comment: Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Actually I'm facing the same problem at this moment and hopefully will figure it out, be patient.

Comment: any suggestions?